# "Mode not supported" on my Samsung tv

Tags: linux, debian, hdmi, armbian, bananapi

I'm using Banana Pi with Armbian, and when I connect my board to TV with HDMI cable, on TV's screen appears `Mode not supported`.
My ***armbianEnv.txt*** looks like:

```
verbosity=1
logo=disabled
console=both
disp_mode=1024x768p50e
overlay_prefix=sun7i-a20
rootdev=UUID=da7fde2c-8e42-4cb9-a8f2-20692463ff4e
rootfstype=ext4
usbstoragequirks=0x2537:0x1066:u,0x2537:0x1068:u
```